# Direct SQL query in wordpress/formidable pro

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to do a sql query to get all data from form db like this:

```
Id name address
102 John Tokyo
10 Eva Paris
...
```

Problem with this query is in aggregation function, it select only one and max value.
Will somebody help me? I'm not really good at php, sql.

Thanks.

I'm running MySQL. 
Here is `formidable` database schema:
http://formidablepro.com/knowledgebase/database-schema/

```
SELECT 
  wp_frm_items.id AS store_id,
  MAX(
    IF(
      wp_frm_item_metas.field_id = 224,
      wp_frm_item_metas.meta_value,
      ""
    )
  ) NAME,
  MAX(
    IF(
      wp_frm_item_metas.field_id = 225,
      wp_frm_item_metas.meta_value,
      ""
    )
  ) address 
FROM
  wp_frm_items,
  wp_frm_item_metas 
WHERE wp_frm_items.id = wp_frm_item_metas.item_id 
  AND wp_frm_item_metas.field_id IN (224, 225) 
GROUP BY wp_frm_items.id
```

Comment: So what do you need if not max?All values?SUM of all values?

Comment: I dont know how to get in this db specific schema all entries from form.  Thats my problem.

Comment: I figure out, it works as i wanted. We can close. Thanks